# an unexpected, thorough, continual feeling of pleasure

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Imagine having a massage, but it's not a normal deep-tissue massage. Something would happen that provides more than 'relief wrapped in pain'.  Rather, a thorough, continual, never-before-felt pleasure.

When you take a small risk and the resultant *feeling* is FAR better and something you never expected and probably haven't experienced.

In some cases, you knew it *could* have happened to you, but definitely weren't expecting the level or type of pleasure.

Similar phrases that don't seem to hit the mark:

- almost a visceral, pleased shock
- a surprising satisfaction
- a delightful surprise

Here's [a similar question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/242860/word-phrase-for-seeing-something-for-the-first-time-and-being-impressed), where the answer is "striking". But, I'm **not** looking for an adjective describing the object that causes the feeling.  I'm looking for what the person *feels*.

If a single word is difficult to find, I'd prefer a 2-word phrase using common words.

---

- [unexpected pleasure](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/95980/is-there-a-word-meaning-unexpected-pleasure) doesn't describe the level of pleasure
- treat is too "candy-like" and not as "continual"

Comment: Perhaps euphoric?

Comment: @jacksmith that's dang near ;D

Answer (score 2):

Euphoria: a feeling or state of intense excitement and happiness.
"the euphoria of success will fuel your desire to continue training"

Comment: The OP seems to want a noun.  Thus ***euphoria***

Comment: Elation is good, too.